# How to Create Linked Service in Azure Data Factory

Tags: c#, azure, azure-data-factory, azureportal

Creating Linked Services in Azure Data Factory (ADF),

- Create Linked Service in Azure Data Factory using.Net Custom Activity for the following link,
  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/quickstart-create-data-factory-dot-net#create-a-linked-service
- I used applicationId from registered App in ADF
- I don't want to execute .Net (Azure SDK .Net) locally because I have ubuntu machine and also I can't use PowerShell script. so I used the Azure function to run Linked Service
- I used authenticate ADF using Client Credential

Any other way to create Linked Service in Azure UI?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create linked service in azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47551527/how-to-create-linked-service-in-azure)

Comment: how could be create linked service from azure portal? @PeterBons

Comment: Providing you have access rights see this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/v1/data-factory-copy-activity-tutorial-using-azure-portal#create-linked-services.

Comment: Are you using v1 or v2 (preview) of adf?

Comment: I'm using V2. Now I have successfully created linked service using .net custom activity but I don't see actions for Author & deploy in the home view of ADF.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the ADF V2 preview only has programmatic authoring experiences (see the public reference docs for details of REST, .NET, Powershell, Python), however we plan to preview some new authoring UI for V2 within next couple months, when that's available it will have a link/tile in the azure portal factory blade similar to the current Monitor & Manage.